# Figuring x,y,z end points

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle

I'm trying to calculate x,y,z endpoints based on a length and two angles.

So if my starting point is 0,0,0, length (l) = 100, Angle 1 (A1) is 35 and Angle 2 (A2) is 15, what would be the equation to solve this for? (BTW, this for playing around with some software I have - 4NEC2).

Comment: What are these angles? Between what lines?

Comment: It's one line, A1 would be the angle for Y,Z an then A2 would be for X,Y.

X being back to front, Y being left to right and Z being up and down,